# Manter valor de input de um reactive form após um submit

Tags: angular

Tenho um reactive form simples que ao ser salvado, apaga o registro do meu input.
Estou tentando manter o valor após o salvar. Mas não estou conseguindo.

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()" class="form-inline">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <label class="control-label">Currículo Lattes</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"
        id="curriculoLattes"
        placeholder="Ex.: Link do currículo"
        formControlName="linkCurriculoLattes"
        value="text">

      <button
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-success"
        style="margin: 10px 0;"
        disableButtonDuringRequest
        [disabled]="!form.hasChanges">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
          Salvar Currículo Lattes
      </button>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
salvar() {
  const model = this.form.getRawValue();

  let request;
  if (this.edicao) {
    request = this.pessoaService
      .alterarCurriculoLattes(this.idPessoa, model);
  } else {
    request = this.pessoaService
      .salvarCurriculoLattes(this.idPessoa, model);
  }

  this.subscribtions.add(
    request.subscribe((result) => {
      if (result) {
        this.edicao = true;
        this.setFormularioSemAlteracao(this.form);
        this.store.dispatch(actions.salvarCurriculoLattes(model));

        this.services
          .notification
          .exibirMensagemDeSucesso('Currículo lattes salvo com sucesso.');
      }
    })
  );
}

setFormularioSemAlteracao(form = null) {
  if (form) {
    form.markAsPristine();
    form.markAsUntouched();
    form.hasChanges = false;
   } else {
     this.form.markAsPristine();
     this.form.markAsUntouched();
     this.form.hasChanges = false;
   }
}
```

Tentei inserir

> value="linkCurriculoLattes ? linkCurriculoLattes : null"

Mas não obtive sucesso.
também tentei

> [value]="linkCurriculoLattes ? linkCurriculoLattes : null"

mas retornou o erro:

> Identifier 'linkCurriculoLattes' is not defined. The component
>   declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do
>   not contain such a member

Comment: O que esse método `setFormularioSemAlteracao` faz? Coloque seu conteúdo na pergunta

Comment: @Costamilam pronto.

Comment: Em algum momento você chama `form.reset()` ou `form.patchValue()` ou `form.setValue()`? Esses são os métodos geralmente usados para alterar os valores de um controle

Comment: Essa é a questão, eu não chamo em momento algum haha.

Comment: Você pode ir debbugando seu código e ver em qual momento o formulário é resetado. Não é o ideal, mas pode guardar previamente o valor do formulário e setar ele novamente no final da submissão